# How to catch QueryException error when using Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel

I tested my app to disallow duplication of emails. It works, however I can't catch the error or it doesn't display the request error in the form page whenever it found duplication.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'admin@DOMAIN.com' for key 'admins_email_unique'

I already tried overriding the RegisterController, but still can't find where the error is being fetch first.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    try{
        return Admin::create([
        'role_id' => $data['role_id'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    }

    catch(Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
    {
         echo($e);
    }
}
```

My current RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuth;

use App\Admin;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Traits\RoleTrait;

 class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;
use RoleTrait;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/admin/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin.guest');
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
        return Admin::create([
        'role_id' => $data['role_id'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

}


/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'role_id' => 'required|string|max:4',
        'username' => 'required|string|unique:users|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $mgaAdminRoleNames = $this->getAdminRoleNames();
    return view('admin.auth.register')->with('adminRoleNames',$mgaAdminRoleNames);
}
/**
 * Get the guard to be used during registration.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

I already put in admin\auth\register.blade.php

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
         <span class="invalidMessage">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
@endif
```

The expected solution either of this two: 
**1) Display error in the form page like this:**

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkHOm.png)

2) Or catch the QueryException and echo the error directly

Comment: use laravel validator

Comment: already tried bro. I'm using the default auth code. It has already the validator. My code is: return Validator::make($data, [
                    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

Comment: didn't see you including the validation

Comment: @Beginner I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer while I'm checking the validator. So if anyone encounter this problem. Here's the solution:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'role_id' => 'required|string|max:4',
        'username' => 'required|string|unique:admins|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:admins',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Notice the **"unique"** attribute. I change it from **"users"** to **"admins"**.

I think the word "admins" came from config\auth.php directory where you set your guards and providers stuff.

Answer (score 0):

use validations for duplicate entry i hope this link will be helpful [laravel recommended link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

Comment: thanks man. I will try to overlook again the documentation hopefully I'll found a solution